# Display Progress Bar while Uploading Files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project in which I have to implement file upload functionality, User will upload the file, while uploading I have to do two things
1: Send Email to admin
2: Make Zip file of uploaded file.

I have to show Progress bar during these 2 processes like below

[image]

I have tried using [this](http://demo.essentialobjects.com/Demos/Progress%20Bar/Server%20Side%20Task%20-%20Advanced%201/Demo.aspx) but it doesn't support manually start on button click event. How can I Implement this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a third-party upload control for that, such as [SlickUpload](http://slickupload.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to start it in a new thread and when the process is done you will have to stop it. Use a session variable to control if its started or finished.